# Jmeter Request using Json File - Manilupate Json File

Tags: json, post, jmeter, patch, jmeter-5.0

i have to Create a Jmeter Script to use informations coming from a json (`

```js
{
    "enabled": true,
    "sort": null,
    "description": null,
    "external_id": null,
    "name": "Country",
    "id": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
    "values": [
        {
            "enabled": true,
            "sort": 4,
            "external_id": null,
            "name": "World",
            "id": "295e9c1a-2cbc-445f-aa5e-c1ac409953b3",
            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
            "parent": null,
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "id": 1546,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "rights_matrix_attributes_id": {
                        "id": "3457484a-fe54-4243-ba18-963b55d527e3",
                        "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                        "name": "Geoblocking",
                        "sort": null,
                        "source": null,
                        "type": "Switch"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 1547,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "rights_matrix_attributes_id": {
                        "id": "fec573bd-56a5-46bf-a475-f1a7088301d0",
                        "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                        "name": "Geoblocking Methods Allowed",
                        "sort": null,
                        "source": "geoblocking_methods",
                        "type": "Dropdown"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "id": 1548,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "rights_matrix_attributes_id": {
                        "id": "cdd1a096-f84d-478c-9922-3dac6db2c06a",
                        "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                        "name": "Overspill",
                        "sort": null,
                        "source": null,
                        "type": "Switch"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "children": [
                {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "sort": 0,
                    "external_id": null,
                    "name": "Europe",
                    "id": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                    "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                    "parent": "295e9c1a-2cbc-445f-aa5e-c1ac409953b3",
                    "attributes": [],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": -1,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Italy",
                            "id": "d8b009a1-db39-4b9c-82aa-61946728cdc6",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 1,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Spain",
                            "id": "ade3569b-a2fa-456d-a816-54740ffdc7c1",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 4,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Austria",
                            "id": "ff2642cc-101b-4ab8-9e3f-6bef9e99a3d8",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 4,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Portugal",
                            "id": "ef4666fa-cb6b-4c98-afa4-a0bd82f76008",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 4,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Denmark",
                            "id": "edd11da2-5ebe-4969-9a74-8d229d4df1d1",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 4,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "France",
                            "id": "70ebade9-674a-45da-8215-33a72161192f",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 4,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Poland",
                            "id": "1402e269-96ef-49af-b7dd-a04c80a22401",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "ff6fa181-22a6-484c-acd9-c802ff5b0a63",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "sort": 0,
                    "external_id": null,
                    "name": "Asia",
                    "id": "a2b259ce-ce7d-456b-943e-74522ead0cc9",
                    "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                    "parent": "295e9c1a-2cbc-445f-aa5e-c1ac409953b3",
                    "attributes": [],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Japan",
                            "id": "af9ce4db-7a93-4cde-96c5-00bdaff11280",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "a2b259ce-ce7d-456b-943e-74522ead0cc9",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Thailand",
                            "id": "215bc143-6833-4449-99c6-57a61bb6630f",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "a2b259ce-ce7d-456b-943e-74522ead0cc9",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "China",
                            "id": "12eb5afa-aab1-4a9d-8963-b206874233a3",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "a2b259ce-ce7d-456b-943e-74522ead0cc9",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "sort": 0,
                    "external_id": null,
                    "name": "Oceania",
                    "id": "96edeb00-e0b2-45e8-8a86-b643f3844ac1",
                    "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                    "parent": "295e9c1a-2cbc-445f-aa5e-c1ac409953b3",
                    "attributes": [],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": -1,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Australia",
                            "id": "485932e1-4590-4f07-8eb5-ed06e531bfad",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "96edeb00-e0b2-45e8-8a86-b643f3844ac1",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 1,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "New Zeland",
                            "id": "7826526e-445a-4bc9-9677-a4b837a96097",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "96edeb00-e0b2-45e8-8a86-b643f3844ac1",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "sort": 0,
                    "external_id": null,
                    "name": "America",
                    "id": "280c614b-332e-4759-a9a3-2b83a6d0920e",
                    "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                    "parent": "295e9c1a-2cbc-445f-aa5e-c1ac409953b3",
                    "attributes": [],
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Canada",
                            "id": "fbe84911-21e4-408b-8862-a3f42b9757c4",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "280c614b-332e-4759-a9a3-2b83a6d0920e",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Brazil",
                            "id": "d8c9bef5-4363-404f-9515-920bd1da0c82",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "280c614b-332e-4759-a9a3-2b83a6d0920e",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "United States",
                            "id": "879db053-d151-4625-b326-6e32abfb4da0",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "280c614b-332e-4759-a9a3-2b83a6d0920e",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Mexico",
                            "id": "78f0fbd3-4ece-4ad5-9c10-df953737f3f4",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "280c614b-332e-4759-a9a3-2b83a6d0920e",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        },
                        {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "sort": 0,
                            "external_id": null,
                            "name": "Argentina",
                            "id": "6b1f9421-665a-4fb8-b3ce-fbcb2862f0fa",
                            "dimension": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f",
                            "parent": "280c614b-332e-4759-a9a3-2b83a6d0920e",
                            "attributes": [],
                            "children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to extract all single values  including children but i want to exclude attributes. Then i have to use the extracted single parent/children value (without attributes) in a  single POST request (Value Creation), then i have to include in a PATCH  request (Value Update) the single Value together with its attributes ( i don't know how to extract them), then i have to make another PATCH request( Add child value to parent Value) and i need the id of the single Value and the id of the children Value. Its a little tricky i Know :). The number of requests have to follow the number of values. Attributes and children can be added in the same request i think. Values children can have children. Thank you :)
Post Request Body: (

```js
{"name":"Italian","enabled":true,"dimension":"9afe6729-0d9c-4d7d-be40-5ec3e308f2e3","consumption_type":null, "id": "cac65eb2-d443-4f77-afc5-379c37750a2f", "sort": null, "description": null,"external_id": null}
```

First PATCH Request to add Attributes to Value:

```js
{"enabled":true,"sort":0,"external_id":null,"name":"Italian","date_updated":null,"date_created":"2023-09-13T10:24:36.584Z","consumption_type":null,"user_updated":null,"user_created":"2eea50dc-ffff-4fdf-8593-238ffde6d8c1","id":"39568be1-f909-4320-b53c-5fbfaa3c0504","dimension":"9afe6729-0d9c-4d7d-be40-5ec3e308f2e3","attributes":[{"enabled":true,"rights_matrix_attributes_id":{"id":null,"name":"Prova","type":"Input","source":null}}]}
```

second PATCH request payload to add children values:

```js
{"dimension":"9afe6729-0d9c-4d7d-be40-5ec3e308f2e3","id":"39568be1-f909-4320-b53c-5fbfaa3c0504","children":["6d9dd3e3-38a0-49a8-85e6-c167256e2fbd"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how these 3 requests are connected with the response you're getting as the attributes values are different and it's unclear whether they're coming from the original response or they're generated.

For example there is no `Italian` anywhere in the "informations", there is no dimension `9afe6729-0d9c-4d7d-be40-5ec3e308f2e3` anywhere in the "informatinos", etc.

Most probably you will need to generate request body using [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy). See [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) article for more details.

Comment: yes the data are different as i tried from front end to add a random value, by the way the dimension id is a data that i can retrieve myself, and italian is the name of the value